# Tomcat 8 - Unable to find setter method for attribute

Tags: jsp, tomcat8

I have jsp file which has customtag with attributes called userRole,companyID as below and corresponding tld file and java file to set and get the attribute values. when I try to load the page tomcat 8 server throwing exception as **"Unable to find setter method for attribute: userRole"**

Can some1 help me what was the problem. Below are the code snippets

**jsp file**

```
<dp:bankName
        userRole='<%=request.getAttribute("user_role")%>'
        companyID='${viewBean.companyID}'
</dp:bankName>
```

**tld file**

```
<tag>
        <name>bankName</name>
        <tag-class>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.DisplayBankNameTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>JSP</body-content>
                <attribute>
            <name>companyID</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>userRole</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
```

**java file**

```
private String companyID = null;
private String userRole = null;

public String getCompanyID() {
    return companyID;
}

public void setCompanyID(String companyID) {
    this.companyID = companyID;
}

public String getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(Object userRole) {
    if (null != userRole) {
        this.userRole = (String) userRole;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```
public void setUserRole(Object userRole) {
```

to:

```
public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
```

In addition, remove `(String)` from `this.userRole = (String) userRole;`.

Comment: Hi, I already tried your approach its worked. Could you please tell me what was the problem why should we change it from Object to String. I want to know what was the exact problem behind this

Comment: Please read [the document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm). `type - Defines the Java class-type of this attribute. By default it is assumed as String`